# Whats a good approach/pattern to solve this scheduling problem

Tags: design-patterns

I have an object

```
public class Task
{
    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
    public IList<Task> Dependencies { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

which has dependencies on other instances. For example:

(read "<-" as "depends on")

- B <- A
- C <- A
- D <- B,C

and

- Q <- P
- R <- Q

Given a list of Tasks* and an EndDate, I need to set the StartDate on each task such that they will all be completed by the EndDate. Tasks may run in parallel where possible, so....

A has to be completed before B and C (which can be done at the same time), and D can only be run after B and C are both complete.

R must run after Q, after P, but these can be run in parelell to A B C and D.

* the list will be complete, all dependencies will be present in the list

Thanks for any advice
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

A [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) and [Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort)?

Comment: presumably id want to split ABCD and PQR into two separate lists before sorting them

Comment: Start from the end and build the tree bottom up?

Comment: @dirkgently that was my idea. Find all the tasks that arent a dependency of another task, then just work backwards. Seems straightforward to me

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the critical path. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107660/how-to-compute-the-critical-path-of-a-directional-acyclic-graph) if it helps.

Otherwise, it's an easy dynamic programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more of a syncronization activity.  I.e.  in threading you would use WaitHandles.

A starts and passes B a wait handle AND C a wait handle

Once A finishes B and C start due to the wait handle being signalled

D has a wait handle that waits for ANY on B and C , so who ever finishs first will signal D

Answer (score 0):

For small graphs, just calculate the start date recursively - the start date of D will be `min(B.StartDate,C.StartDate) - D.Length`.

For large graphs, perform a topological sort then you can perform the calculations iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Task
    {
        public long Length;
        public List<Task> Dependencies = new List<Task>();
        public DateTime StartDate;
        public DateTime EndDate;

        public void CompleteBaseSchedule()
        {
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            foreach (Task task in Dependencies)
            {
             startDate = (startDate < task.EndDate) ? task.EndDate : startDate;
                task.CompleteBaseSchedule();

            }
            this.StartDate = startDate;
            this.Length = this.EndDate.Ticks - this.StartDate.Ticks;
        }
```

somewhere in the main:

```
            Task task1 = new Task();
            task1.EndDate = new DateTime(2009, 3, 3);
            Task task2 = new Task();
            task1.EndDate = new DateTime(2009, 3, 5);
            Task task3 = new Task();
            task1.EndDate = new DateTime(2009, 3, 2);
            Task task4 = new Task();
            task1.EndDate = new DateTime(2009, 3, 6);
            task4.Dependencies.AddRange(new Task[]{ task1, task2, task3 });

            task4.CompleteBaseSchedule();
            Console.WriteLine(task4.StartDate);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones' advice, the Topological sort stuff was useful, but I think i've solved it an easier way...

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Task> tasks;
    private readonly DateTime endDate;

    public Scheduler(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, DateTime endDate)
    {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public void Schedule()
    {
        var terminators = FindTerminators();
        SetStartDatesRecursively(terminators, endDate);
    }

    public ICollection<Task> FindTerminators()
    {
        IList<Task> terminators = new List<Task>();

        foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            var dependencies = this.tasks.Where(x => x.Dependencies.Contains(task));
            if (dependencies.Count() == 0)
                terminators.Add(task);
        }

        return terminators;
    }

    public void SetStartDatesRecursively(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, DateTime endDate)
    {
        foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            var startDate = endDate - task.Length;

            if (task.StartDate.HasValue)
                task.StartDate = startDate < task.StartDate ? startDate : task.StartDate;
            else
                task.StartDate = startDate;

            SetStartDatesRecursively(task.Dependencies, task.StartDate.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you elaborate on the solution?
THX

Comment: FindTerminators (probably not the correct terminology) finds all the "leaf" nodes of the graph, i.e. nodes with no exiting paths - from the example, D and R. It then recurses up the tree from D and R covering each node, setting the start date to as early as required.